# Can a easeljs hitarea be set using image data?

Tags: javascript, png, easeljs

I'd like to be able to set set the hit area of my Display objects using image data instead of a Shape object. However setting the hitarea property of my objects doesn't seem to be working. Here's an example of what I'm attempting.

Say we have this sprite sheet for a button:

[example of sprite sheet button with 3 frames. frame 3 is a hitmask](https://files.secureserver.net/0sg47LAJrziPAo)
(Sorry my rep. isn't high enough to just post the image)


I have a function to get my hitmask frame and make it into a bitmap this isn't working.

```
/* Not the exact code, syntax may be a bit off */

var myButton = new createjs.Container() // assume this is an object with mouse events
var myExtractedFrame = ExtractFrame(myButton._sprite, 2) // a createjs Bitmap of frame the hitmask frame

myButton.hitArea = myExtractedFrame // will this work??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should work. The `hitArea` property supports the use of any display object.

Without seeing more code, it's difficult to guess what you're doing wrong, so here is an example of it working correctly with `Sprite` instances (which is likely a more efficient approach than extracting frames into `Bitmap` instances): http://jsfiddle.net/6L5esy6v/

Comment: Thanks Grant, I'm not entirely sure what I was doing wrong, but after updating to version .8 everything is working much better.